# Git Pull Origin Master - not working?

Tags: 7, version-control

Me and my friend share a pantheon site that we are pulling / pushing from together. However when I go to the Dev site and I noticed some changes (like a page being empty) and on my local, that same page being full of text.. When I do "Git Pull Origin Master", it tells me i'm already up-to-date.

Why doesn't it pull the changes down?

Comment: If the missing text is provided by code, you might just need to clear caches. If it's content, you'll need to sync the database separately. A VCS is only for code, not content

Comment: You may need to run `update.php` or `drush updb` as well...